# What is Box2d, and how could I use it to make flash games?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, box2d

I heard that it is a physics engine, and I could use it to simulate the throwing of a ball. What exactly is it, and how would I use it with AS3 and Flash CS5.5? Tutorials???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box2D is a physics engine, so basically it runs along side your code and does purely abstract simulation. Each frame (or however often you wish) you do a "step" through the physics world, which updates the simulation by a single step, and then in your code you can read these values and apply them to your movieclips or whatever you'd like to use that data for.

As far as tutorials, the best source for them in my opinion is http://www.emanueleferonato.com/category/box2d/. Note that when it comes to flash you have your pick of implementations. You have the standard, pure AS3 implementation and the Alchemy implementation, which is faster. One of the alchemy versions is called the WCK or world construction kit. You can set it up to work with Flash CS as a sort of plugin, which allows you to visually construct your physical world using the IDE instead of code. Check it out [here](http://www.sideroller.com/wck/). You can also find a video tutorial for the WCK [here](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=135).

Answer (score 0):

you can download box2d for flash at :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/box2dflash/

After you download you can see the examples are included within the "Examples" folder. There is a "HelloWorld.fla", where you can start with.

Box2d is a bit complex but very famous 2d engine for flash. And a simple googling can provide you many websites about box 2d flash tutorials. eg : I got this one interesting : http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/08/making-an-as3-game-in-box2d-flash-version-2-0-hello-world-box2d/

Comment: haha, plasticsturgeon is also a member here on SO

Answer (score 0):

there might be a Box2D Air Native Extension already out there (but I'm not sure if it works: https://github.com/mnem/box2d_ane/). I'm very interested in hearing from yours. (sorry couldn't comment on your entry)